# Has there really not been one thing in the past 20 years that provided huge software development gains?

Tags: productivity

In *No Silver Bullet*, Fred Brooks makes a variety of predictions about the future of software engineering, best summed up by:

> There is no single development, in either technology or in management technique, that by itself promises even **one order-of-magnitude improvement** in productivity, in reliability, in simplicity.

His argument is very convincing. Brooks was writing in 1986: was he right? Do developers in 2014 produce software at a rate less than 10x faster than their counterparts in 1986? By some appropriate metric -- how large has the gain in productivity actually been?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16378/discussion-on-question-by-patrick-collins-has-there-really-not-been-one-thing-in).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> Do developers in 2014 produce software at a rate less than 10x faster than their counterparts in 1986?

I would imagine that there's been at least an order of magnitude improvement in productivity since then.  But *not by leveraging one single development,* in either technology or in management technique.

Increases in productivity have come about by a combination of factors. **Note: This is not a comprehensive list:**

1. Better compilers
2. Vastly more powerful computers
3. Intellisense
4. Object orientation
5. Functional orientation
6. Better memory management techniques
7. Bounds checking
8. Static code analysis
9. Strong typing
10. Unit Testing
11. Better programming language design
12. Code generation
13. Source code control systems
14. Code reuse

And so on.  All of these techniques combine to produce productivity gains; there isn't a single silver bullet that has ever produced an order of magnitude speedup.

Note that some of these techniques have existed since the sixties, but have only observed widespread recognition and adoption recently.

Comment: Don't forget better source/version control systems.

Comment: Ah, right.  I would imagine that we could add another dozen (or hundred) things to this list.

Comment: Then why software engineering consistently fails to meet deadlines and budget ?

Comment: @user61852: Because expectations always exceed reality.

Comment: You are right, hence requirement engineering should work harder on lowering client expectations.

Comment: Great answer!  But I'd imagine that having computers that go a few hundred thousand times faster than they did back then helps a little bit too.  Partly by making formerly terrible ideas not be terrible any longer, and partly just by shortening the edit-build-test cycle.

Comment: @user61852 Software exceeds budgets and deadlines so often because there are a lot of gains for the big software houses to do so and almost no penalties to speak of.

Comment: Unit-testing, version control, and continuous integration allow companies like GitHub to [release with every commit](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html). If that isn't an improvement of an order of magnitude, I'm not sure what is.

Comment: @user61852 http://thecodelesscode.com/case/154

Comment: @tmyklebu Moore's Bottleneck is already upon us, and things have gotten terrible again.  There hasn't been a significant improvement in single-engine CPU performance in years.  And while those of us who go back to punched card days would certainly agree that the cycle goes faster now, I wouldn't say it has increased productivity dramatically.

Comment: @RossPatterson: We've basically got what we need for developer tools at this point.  We're even doing stupidly wasteful things with our compiling CPU cycles these days just because we can---look at template metaprogramming.  Remember we're comparing against the '80s; while I certainly wasn't a developer then, I did learn to code on a machine built in 1990.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay It is important to read the full article for "No Silver Bullet" and possibly "No Silver Bullet Revisited" too.  The key point there is that there is no, **one**, ***single***, thing that has increased productivity of programmers by an order of magnitude. Programmers today are likely an order of magnitude than they were in '86 but this is not able to be attributed to one thing. "There is no single development, in either technology or in management technique, that by itself promises even one order-of-magnitude improvement in productivity, in reliability, in simplicity."

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay claiming several distinct items have improved things isn't at issue - but none of them have given us a 10x improvement by themselves from things in the 80s.  Thats what is at the heart of the essay.  Trying to refute it without being aware of its claims doesn't get anyone anywhere.

Comment: Integrated Development Environments should also be included. Personally my coding is at least 2x faster when I use an IDE, not having to manage pesky things like imports, etc.

Comment: @user61852 also keep in mind that coding software is roughly equivalent to the design phase of other professions.  Being overtime and overbudget is common. For example, just look at any new aircraft (notable and recent: the F-35).

Comment: @tmyklebu Every generation of programmers thinks they've basically got everything they need.  Those of us who've got a few generations behind us understand how wrong we were. :-)

Comment: @RossPatterson: Shrug.  I see the ability to use high-level programming languages and optimising compilers and suchlike with freedom as major forward advances.  My understanding is that all that stuff was considered "academic" but it on the cusp of being practical in the mid-'80s.  Doesn't seem like we've got anything in a similar situation today.  (Maybe bugfinders like klee?  I know I'm sinning by predicting the future here, but all the recent "advances" in programming have gone sideways if not backward.  According to me.)

Comment: Leaving the Internet off the list makes the list fairly worthless since it dwarfs all the other reasons combined. The Internet is indeed the only silver bullet. It has increased programmer productivity by multiple orders of magnitude. I have a problem, do a search, I have the solution in seconds. Before the internet, you'd have to spend days creating your custom solution and more days fixing the bugs. Also, you no longer need to spend time memorizing how to use libraries and APIs because looking it up is so easy.

Comment: @Dunk: I didn't spend 90 to 99 percent of my time sitting around looking for documentation before the Internet came along.

Comment: There seems to be an assumption underlying the question, that programmers would actually choose to use something that offered significant demonstrable benefits.  Whether that assumption is justified seems to me to be very much in question.

Answer (score 72):

Robert Harvey's answer is good, but I think he left out what may be the biggest reason why programmers are more productive than ever:  widespread availability of software libraries.

When I started my career there was no STL, .NET, QT, etc.  You had raw C or C++, and that was about it.

Things that used to take days or weeks or work (XML parsing, TCP/IP connections, HTTP communciation) can now be done with a handful of lines of C# code.  This is where we have gotten orders of magnitude better in terms of overall developer productivity.

Our current product uses a docking window framework that we purchased from a vendor.  This let me have a fully functional docking window UI in a matter of minutes.  I shudder to think of what it would take to do that in the days of using the win32 API.

Comment: I would add to this the availability of documentation and assistance. Twenty years ago, you had a mailing list and your immediate colleagues. Now, the programming expertise of the world, in nearly every topic, is available instantly through a single interface.

Comment: @NWard so basically stack overflow =)

Comment: Seems like people just found other (generally better) solutions to problems that avoided the need to parse gigabytes of XML back in the day.

Comment: @tmyklebu `people just found other (generally better) solutions` [citation needed]. Using libraries to quickly parse "mountains" of XML is in many ways better than hand coding unique solutions. XML can certainly be overly terse and repetitive, but the libraries make using it a breeze in most situations.

Comment: @WernerCD terse is not the word I'd use there

Comment: @tmyklebu As painful as it can be to parse large quantities of XML, try parsing large quantities of binary data in an undocumented proprietary format, as would have been produced by most applications written circa 1986.

Comment: @James_pic: I've done that.  Funny enough, it's actually easier.  People didn't make big and stupid and complicated formats because they had to write assembly code to handle whatever format they chose.  They figured out exactly the data they needed to store and stored that and nothing else.  (Oh, and about "undocumented":  assembly code from then is *much* easier to read than assembly code today!)

Comment: @tmyklebu No one needed gigabytes of anything back in the day (or even megabytes!).  What generates that amount of XML is the fact that we are storing and tracking way more data than ever.  james_pic is right, XML is way better than having a bazillion proprietary binary formats kicking around.  XML may be wordy, but it is cross-platform, human readable, and highly flexible.  Those are all valuable traits.

Comment: @17of26: Not convinced.  What generates that amount of XML is the fact that we use XML for it.  And what we get today is a bazillion proprietary XML formats that are no more cross-platform, human-readable, or highly-flexible than their binary counterparts from 25 years ago.  (No, using ASCII or Unicode or whatever does not make something human-readable.)  And not very much data needs to be tree-structured to begin with.

Comment: XML is absolutely more cross-platform than a binary format.  With XML, you don't have to worry about byte swapping.  With binary formats, for every exchange between a client and a server you need to figure out whether or not byte swapping is needed and then perform the swap if needed.

Comment: @17of26: But you *do* still have to worry about byte swapping!  UCS-2 and UCS-4 can both encode characters in either big-endian or little-endian format!  It's much less onerous to worry about byte swapping in binary formats; you just call `le32toh` whenever you access a field.  You get the exact representation of floating-point numbers, too, without having to trust some probably broken conversion library.  Oh, and a `double` always takes eight bytes.  Oh, and you don't triple (or worse) the size of your file in pursuit of these goals you aren't going to attain.

Comment: I agree: the single improvement in technology that led to an order of magnitude increase in productivity was code reuse.  The internet though is a wash.  On the one hand it's far easier to get quick information in a timely matter, on the other it can be a huge time suck.

Answer (score 62):

For the sake of argument, **I disagree with the assertion of Fred Brooks**.

**There is an improvement in technology which allowed alone an order-of-magnitude improvement in productivity: internet**, and more precisely the progressive availability of internet connection in every home in the last two decades.

Being able to find instantly an answer to nearly every problem you can encounter as a developer enables a huge boost in productivity. Don't know how to select nth element in JQuery? Google search leads to an answer of [the exact question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element). Don't know how to use `overflow` in CSS? [Mozilla's MDN is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). Forgot what `virtual` keyword means in C#? [Google helps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx), again.

When I started programming, I didn't have internet. I had books, as well as some digital-format documentation stored locally, but searching through books and documentation was a slow process, and no matter how much books I had, there were *many* issues that weren't mentioned there.

More importantly, nearly every problem you encounter was already encountered by somebody else before. Internet helps finding people who had this error and successfully solved it. This is not a sort of information you find in books or official documentation like MSDN. Instead, such information is usually found:

- **On Stack Overflow, obviously.** For example, I haven't seen any book which mentioned [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20561990/240613).
- **In blogs.** I found *a lot* of help on blogs when I had particular problems, would it be with WCF configuration or a proxy server which doesn't start or a cryptic bug when using a specific API on a machine with culture different from en-US.
- **In bug reports concerning open source software.** For example, it was very helpful recently when I attempted to use Ubuntu's MAAS and when I used PXE. You don't find this sort of information in books either.

The importance of the immediate availability of an answer to most issues one can encounter is especially noticeable if we take in account that most of the time a team spends on a project is spent **maintaining** it.

- Internet doesn't help much during architecture and design phases (Programmers.SE might help, but it would be much more valuable for an architect to read books about architecture and design, to learn design patterns, etc.).
- It starts to be helpful during testing and implementation steps, when actual issues arise.
- But **most issues appearing during the maintenance, it's there when help from others through internet appears crucial**. Basic example: a WCF service works perfectly well *on my machine*, but fails with no exception whatsoever when deployed in production, while it worked for the last two weeks. This happened to me, and I'm thankful to blog writers and Stack Overflow community for helping me solving the issue in a matter of hours rather than weeks.

Would it justify a x10 increase in productivity? Difficult to tell.

- On one hand, there are cases where you find an answer immediately, while you could have spent days searching for it alone (or be forced to rewrite a large part of the application).
- On the other hand, the overall productivity improved based on multiple factors, such as better project management (Agile, TDD etc. comes to mind), better team management ([Radical Management](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470548681) by Stephen Denning comes to mind), better tools (debuggers, profilers, IDEs, etc.), better hardware (no, I won't be very productive if forced to write in Assembler for a slow CPU and very limited RAM), etc.

Comment: "Internet" is not a single development either.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I would qualify it as a *technology* from the Brooks' quote. But I agree, the terms may not be obvious: first, would it be Internet (early 1980s) or World Wide Web (1989)? Second, it's not *just* the technology itself which was essential, but its popularity.

Comment: But the things we pile under the concept of "Internet" involve many different technologies.  There's multiple generations of World Wide Web (DHTML/Javascript/browser).  There's the fibre optic advances that make datacenter-scale connections possible.  There are the CMOS process improvements that allow servers to have a terabyte of RAM and perform data mining.  Algorithms to index a million questions about programming and provide the 10 closest hits in some natural language sense.

Comment: People working with the systems Brooks designed didn't need Google to remember how to write JCL. These systems came with well-documented development environments that were leveraged continually / improved incrementally over the decades. Whether due to planned obsolescence or something less sinister, we’ve gotten away from that. In any case, I'm hesitant to call what we have now an improvement, and completely unwilling to declare it a "silver bullet".

Comment: Complexity is the enemy. You could hold JCL in your head and hold the manual in your hand; a single shelf could document the whole system. Now there has been a huge explosion in the size of systems and their underlying rate of change.

Comment: As obsolete as it sounds, I can still find useful information on usenet groups.

Answer (score 13):

I'd say the internet is a pretty good candidate. StackOverflow and Google are a modern-day developer's most powerful tools. Instant knowledge-sharing on a global basis! These days you don't need to know the answers, you only need to know how to *get to know* the answers - and that is a perfectly adequate subsitute that allows developers to spend less time reading and more time coding, and thus being productive. It means that every programmer in the world has access to *all* of the answers, and all they need to do is know how to ask the right questions.

Comment: You are the only person to point out the silver bullet. Not only has it made programmers more productive by a magnitude, but actually by multiple magnitudes of order.

Comment: +1000 - you can get help in a few minutes instead working for a few days on an obscure issue.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest that trends pulling us in the other direction (i.e. toward lower productivity) are at least as strong as the trends you asked about. The experience of doing client/server development tool like VB6 or PowerBuilder came pretty close to the "Rapid Application Development" (RAD) ideal. You got to draw your forms, and there were obvious hooks for your procedural or SQL code.

Web development, at least initially, destroyed a lot of the techniques and infrastructure that made these things possible, and many client/server developers just stopped being developers, or clung desperately to, say, VB6.

The transition to heavily client-driven Web development was yet another slash-and-burn experience; Microsoft was getting back to the RAD ideal with WebForms, and then it quickly fell out of favor. Instead developers were expected to abuse the infrastructure (e.g. XMLHttpRequest, which is seldom used for XML) and otherwise monkey around at a low level of abstraction in an effort to make their websites more interactive

There are good reasons behind all of these transitions, and it's not fair to compare a process that yielded a native .EXE (requiring installtion and management at the individual client) to Web development, nor is it completely fair to compare a process that relies heavily on postbacks with one that yields a more seamless experience. But I will say that the practices currently in vogue result in some surprisingly low-level thought processes among people who missed out on client/server, RAD, and the like. Client/server buttons just worked, and one certainly did not have to worry about the underlying data channels that got data to the event handlers that made this happen.

Conversely, more contemporary developers tend to think that those of us who did client/server development (or even postback-based Web development) have a tendency to resort to shortcuts (and mean that in a bad way). That's understandable, but I still think that the way contemporary development is done is surprisingly low level, and the days of searching for a "silver bullet" seem to have given way to the era of mocking those of us who question the wisdom of mining and smelting our own lead.

Comment: have you seen Meteor.js?

Comment: @strugee Yes, and I think Meteor.js may be a step in the right direction. Still, though, the fact that we've essentially "started over" technologically at least 3-4 times since Brooks wrote his book (referring here to the transition to the PC, then to client/server, then to Web, and then to AJAX) is arguably what's kept us from finding the "silver bullet" or even making linear improvements in productivity. Time will tell how long the current development techniques endure (and improve). There are some reasons for optimism... everyone is now reaching for a robust, cross-platform point.

Answer (score 5):

Technology has advanced very much and now we have all the things Robert Harvey enumerates in his answer, but:

- The problem seems to be **changing requirements**. The client knows that there will not be waste of materials when changing the requirements of a software project, so they do. That kind of requirement changes almost never happen once a physical-world project like a building, is half done.
- Another important aspect is that programming continues to be highly **handiwork**. Rarely if ever, RAD-generated code goes into production without being modified by hand first.
- Code continues to be **highly complex**, and that complexity doesn't seem to decrease with new technologies.
- The rate of **deadlines not met** or budgets exceeded continues to be greater that those in other disciplines, and often times technical debt is incurred in order to meet them, generating hidden costs.
- Something that have, without a doubt, happened is that **compartmentalization** has ocurred. The sheer ammount of technologies one has to know is so that programmers have had to specialized a small number of technologies in order to become really good at them, requiring different kinds of experts to complete a large project.
- One thing that talks about software complexity is that whereas there are literally hundreds of car makers in the world, the list of **companies capable of creating and maintaning an operating system**, (desktop, mobile, embedded or otherwise), can be counted with the fingers of your hands.
- All the above has created a situation in which **there are not enough people studying to be programmers**, so that governments have created campaigns in order to motivate more students into taking that career path.
- One taste of the **maturity** of the software industry is that software licenses continue to state *"<companyX> makes no representations about the suitability of this software for any particular purpose.  It is provided "as is" without express or implied warranty."* Imagine a hardware maker stating that their product is not suitable for any particular purpose. That's the state of the art right now.

Comment: There are certainly more than 10 companies *capable* of creating and maintaining their own OS, but few choose to do so, because other opportunities are more lucrative.

Comment: @BenVoigt Of course, creating and maintaining an OS is comparatively less lucrative out of sheer complexity, requiring decades of research and development, which they should have begun, at latest, in the nineties in order to have a mature product today.

Comment: Also the "return" side of the RoI isn't that good, because the market is already saturated.

Comment: Of course, all you've done is enumerate the well-known roadblocks to effective programming that have been around since shortly after Lady Lovelace picked up her pencil.  The only thing that's different vs 30 years ago is that things have become exponentially more complex.

Answer (score 4):

While one might argue with specific metrics (ie, have things improved by a factor of 9.98?), I (speaking as something of an old-timer) have to agree with the general sentiment of Brooks' comment.

First off, there has been very little truly new technology invented since maybe 1970.  Yes, integrated circuits have gotten longer, lower, wider, and glass fiber has improved communications speeds, but for every step forward there's one back.

Compiler technology has permitted about a 10x improvement in programmer "productivity" vs 1970, when one figures function produced divided by actual coding time, but the proliferation of new or "revised" programming languages and environments means that the average programmer is spending more and more time in "catch up" mode, and less in productive activity.  Apple, Google, and Microsoft all spew out new and substantially incompatible "upgrades" to their environments at a rate that is just below that that would provoke revolt among their serfs ... er, programming customers.  Similarly, HTML/CSS/Javascript/whatever keeps getting more complex.

At one time the rate at which documentation could be produced and propagated would have limited and corralled all this "innovation", but, thanks to the Internet, rigorous documentation is no longer really necessary -- just spew the functions out and rely on bloggers to ferret out the details and make them available.

**Added:**  I've been thinking about this since yesterday, and in particular thinking about the project I worked on from about 1978 until 2008.  This project (the IBM System/38 and its successors) was somewhat unique in that from the start efforts were made to control the complexity of it (one being the division of the software into two roughly equal parts, with a "machine" interface between them).  In the particular area where I worked, several of my coworkers similarly were dedicated to controlling complexity (though we didn't use that term much at the time).  The result was a product that (at first) was quite robust and a "hit" with the customers pretty much from the git-go.  And it was a pleasure to work on -- like playing in a well-trained orchestra.

Of course, over the years complexity crept in, usually at the behest of market planners and managers who had no appreciation for controlling complexity (which is somehow different from just maintaining simplicity).  I don't have the feeling that this was inevitable, but it was impossible to prevent in this case without a manager (like Glenn Henry did originally) pushing back on the forces of confusion.

Comment: But I am reminded of something that occurred to me (and no doubt many others) 20-30 years ago -- there is a sort of Peter Principle of programming (or perhaps a 2nd law of programming thermodynamics) that states that complexity inevitably increases to the point of incomprehensibility.  Things *never* get simpler.

Answer (score 3):

A great deal of what we have learned in software engineering practice in the past 30+ years is of the form "technology X can speed up initial development of new software, but if you don't spend as much or more time thinking about *how* and *when* to use it as you saved by using it, in the long run it will turn your application into a sucking swamp of technical debt, costing you orders of magnitude more time and effort in maintenance."

Technologies that fall under this razor include: hand-coded assembly language, compilers, interpreters, procedure libraries, imperative programming, functional programming, object-oriented programming, manual memory allocation, garbage collection, static types, dynamic types, lexical scope, dynamic scope, "safe" pointers, "unsafe" pointers, the absence of pointers as a language concept, binary file formats, structured-markup file formats, macros, templates, *avoidance* of macros and templates, shared memory, message passing, threads, coroutines, asynchronous event loops, centralized remote services, distributed services, locally installed software, arrays, linked lists, hash tables, and trees.

The fact that many of the items in the above list come in groups which together exhaust the known solution space is very much intentional, and should in and of itself tell you something.  One could argue that the *only* unambiguous, across-the-board improvements in praxis we've had since they first switched on the Z3 are block-structured programming (as opposed to spaghetti code) and memory protection (boy, do I ever *not* miss the days when a typo could take down my entire computer).